# How to add a alarm dynamically through code?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am developing an application to pass a value to alarm through code.
How can I make it possible.
Can I get the intent code and to pass the value to set an alarm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is all the information you need:

[Android AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)